# Why Argo event is always in state Pending?

Tags: argo-workflows, argo-events

I've followed example here https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/sensors/triggers/argo-workflow/ in minikube and after curl post i just get events in state pending with argo list -n argo-events. Could someone please point me what might be the problem about it?

[image]

Comment: Could be a number of things... I wrote a blog post about the things I generally check first: https://dev.to/crenshaw_dev/how-to-debug-an-argo-workflow-31ng

Comment: Looks to me as if the Workflows aren't even making it to a "Pending" state (look at the empty "Status" column). Makes me think Argo Workflows has not been installed, or hasn't been installed to handle workflows on all namespaces.

Comment: @crenshaw-dev exactly, much thx, i feel so dumb :D it has to be namespaced :)

Comment: In my experience, missing only one of the fifty things you have to get right in this setup is a pretty good track record.  Glad to help!